# How do I create an input that can only receive strings?

Tags: python-3.5

I have approached my own question using while loops, if functions and try/except, but have not yet had the desired results.

Here is a method that I have tried recently:

```
Surname2 = input('\nSurname:')
while Surname2 != type('a'): #2
    print('\nPlease define Surname only in letters')
    Surname2 = input('\nSurname:')
    break
```

The error I keep on having here is that it either continues to loop, doesn't receive a string as a string or receives a number as a string.

My aim is to have the users only able to select the supplied options or desired object type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an example using Python.  Get initial user response and then use a while loop to continue getting responses until they enter a valid response.

```
Gender2 = input('Gender (M/F):')

while (Gender2 != "M" and Gender2 != "F"):
   Gender2 = input('Gender (M/F):')
```

I'm not a Python coder so my code could be off but this might give you a good idea on how to do this.  I usually use PHP or PERL.

Answer (score 0):

The following function should do what you want.

```
def get_input(message, choices):
    assert type(message) == type("string"), "Message must be a string"
    assert type(choices) == type([]), "Choices must be an array"
    choice = ""
    out = message + " (" + "/".join(choices) + "): "
    while True:
        c = input(out)
        if c in choices:
            break
        else:
            print "Please enter a valid choice"
    return c
```

Simply call it like the following:

```
get_input("Gender", ["M","F"])
```

Some test calls:

```
Gender (M/F): asdf
Please enter a valid choice
Gender (M/F): 234
Please enter a valid choice
Gender (M/F): 1
Please enter a valid choice
Gender (M/F): 534
Please enter a valid choice
Gender (M/F): zxcv
Please enter a valid choice
Gender (M/F): Ff
Please enter a valid choice
Gender (M/F): Mm
Please enter a valid choice
Gender (M/F): m
Please enter a valid choice
Gender (M/F): f
Please enter a valid choice
Gender (M/F): M
'M'
```